# Inner join en laravel

Tags: laravel-5

tengo esta consulta con varios inner join y bueno, no se bien como se trabaja en laravel, ya lo intente pero me marca este error: General error: -104 Dynamic SQL Error SQL error code = -104 Token unknown - line 1

```html
SELECT 
A.CODIGO, A.IDENTIFICACION, A.DESCRIPCION, A.FORMATO, A.LIBRE1 PRESENTACION, A.PIEZASCAJA, A.CODIGO_BARRAS, A.PRECIO_COSTE,
F.CODIGO CODIGO_FAMILIA, F.NOMBRE FAMILIA, SUM(L.CANTIDAD*L.OPERACION*L.ESTADO) PIEZAS

FROM
ARTICULO A
INNER JOIN FAMILIAS F ON F.CODIGO=A.FAMILIA
INNER JOIN LINALMAC L ON L.ARTICULO=A.CODIGO

WHERE
    
A.PIEZASCAJA=1
AND
L.ALMACEN=1
```

Intente con esto:

```
 $articulos = DB::table('ARTICULO')
                        ->join('FAMILIAS','FAMILIAS.CODIGO','=','ARTICULO.FAMILIA')
                        ->join('LINALMAC','LINALMAC.ARTICULO','=','ARTICULO.CODIGO')
                        ->select('ARTICULO.CODIGO', 'ARTICULO.IDENTIFICACION', 'ARTICULO.DESCRIPCION', 'ARTICULO.FORMATO', 'ARTICULO.LIBRE1 AS PRESENTACION', 'ARTICULO.PIEZASCAJA', 'ARTICULO.CODIGO_BARRAS', 'ARTICULO.PRECIO_COSTE',
            'FAMILIAS.CODIGO AS CODIGO_FAMILIA', 'FAMILIAS.NOMBRE FAMILIA', 'SUM(LINALMAC.CANTIDAD*LINALMAC.OPERACION*LINALMAC.ESTADO) AS PIEZAS',)
                        ->where('ARTICULO.PIEZASCAJA',1)
                        ->where('LINALMAC.ALMACEN',1)
                        ->get();
```

Comment: Agrega por favor lo que intentaste en Laravel

Comment: listo, ya lo edite

Comment: Al final de tu método select tienes una coma de más con quitarla debería funcionar, por favor confirma si se resolvió

Comment: cierto, bueno aunque quite eso sigue marcando el error que ya mencione

Comment: Con que gestor de bases de datos trabajas?

Comment: Cuando utilizo `select` suelo poner los elementos en un array, puedes intentarlo de esta forma `select(['elemento', 'otro'])`

Comment: Aparte de la coma sobrante que ya señaló @Aprendiz no veo error en tu código. Si hay más contexto donde lo estás usando pon el contexto completo, pues no parece ser un error relativo a la consulta en sí. Puede ser problema de conexión a la base de datos u otro.

Comment: Trabajo con Firebird y probare con lo que mencionó @Jonathan

Comment: Gracias por sus respuestas